# unable to install open cv on conda

Tags: python, opencv, conda

I was trying to install open `cv2` on my anaconda its giving me error any one please help me my package details are as following:

```
platform : win-64
          conda version : 4.3.14
       conda is private : False
      conda-env version : 4.3.14
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.6.0.final.0
       requests version : 2.12.4
       root environment :
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the default installation of anaconda on windows, it does not set environment variables for conda package manager. So try using Anaconda Command Prompt(installed with Anaconda package) and then try installing by the following command:

```
    conda install -c menpo opencv
```

This installs opencv version 2.4.x
For other versions go to [Anaconda Cloud](https://anaconda.org/menpo/opencv).

Answer (score 0):

Try to update conda and install opencv again.

```
conda update conda
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```